# temporary redirect when using curl twice on www.seloger.com

Tags: http, curl, setcookie

I'm using *curl -i* from command line to access a certain url on the website https://www.seloger.com and am faced with a problem when I try to access the url more than once from a same wifi network: the first call works fine, I receive all the content from the page which is then displayed on my terminal. On the second call (and all ulterior calls) however the server responds with a **HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect** redirecting to an error page and I don't know why.
I tried from several wifi networks (at home and at work) and each time the same thing happens : first call OK, second call (and all ulterior calls) redirects to error page.

- Here is the curl command:

  ```
  curl -i 'http://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2&naturebien=1,2,4&cp=75'
  ```
- Here is the header of the response after first call :

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: private
  Pragma: no-cache
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Thu, 03 May 2018 07:48:10 GMT
  Vary: User-Agent
  Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=h1f50tvabpvxozh2wcootrog; path=/; HttpOnly
  X-S: X06
  Cache: max-age=10
  X-S: X06
  Cache: max-age=10
  Set-Cookie: SearchAnnDep=75; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: SearchAnnDep=75; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: Compte=; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Wed, 02-May-2018 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: SearchAnnDep=75; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzma=mae059337c-8a5d-4e84-b8d8-26667296db0d6145; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmb=1525340950; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmc=323081068857; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmd=1525340950; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: SearchAnnDep=75; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 07:49:10 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: FirstVisitSeLoger=03/05/2018 09:49:11; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Mon, 19-Nov-2018 08:49:11 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: SearchAnnDep=75; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 07:49:11 GMT; path=/
  Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 07:49:10 GMT
  Content-Length: 361151
  ```
- Here is the header of the response after second call:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Location: /erreur-temporaire/
  Vary: User-Agent
  Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=k4g1xesxplpudif2ze3g4j5e; path=/; HttpOnly
  X-S: X06
  Cache: max-age=10
  X-S: X06
  Cache: max-age=10
  Set-Cookie: __uzma=ma72eea0f2-450c-4016-9549-7880c53778288142; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:53:36 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmb=1525341216; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:53:36 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmc=223201020491; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:53:36 GMT; path=/
  Set-Cookie: __uzmd=1525341216; expires=Sun, 30-Apr-2028 07:53:36 GMT; path=/
  Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 07:53:35 GMT
  Content-Length: 0
  ```

Comment: Are you sending the cookies your received in the response back with the second request?

Comment: No I'm not, only typing the same curl command